# "apt-get install" stuck when build an image from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm tring to build an image from a Dockerfile, and get stuck when "RUN apt-get install ...", i want to know the reason. May be due to GFW, I don't know.
Another thing confused me is that the output log printed when run in build is different from the log printed when run in a container(i.e. run in "docker container run -it image_name /bin/bash"). 
Please help me.

I have tried some keywords like "apt-get install stuck", but i didn't find a similar question.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
MAINTAINER avanetten
ENV CUDNN_VERSION 7.3.0.29
LABEL com.nvidia.cudnn.version="${CUDNN_VERSION}"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-utils \
            libcudnn7=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 \
            libcudnn7-dev=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 && \
    apt-mark hold libcudnn7 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I run this:

```
sudo docker build --no-cache -t testimage .
```

and i stuck here

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.043GB
Step 1/37 : FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
 ---> 2a64416134d8
Step 2/37 : MAINTAINER avanetten
 ---> Running in 0a0f4e3bb485
Removing intermediate container 0a0f4e3bb485
 ---> 23c2cb4ab1ff
Step 3/37 : ENV CUDNN_VERSION 7.3.0.29
 ---> Running in 41b6be7dc176
Removing intermediate container 41b6be7dc176
 ---> 65f16199d658
Step 4/37 : LABEL com.nvidia.cudnn.version="${CUDNN_VERSION}"
 ---> Running in 0f5e7aece401
Removing intermediate container 0f5e7aece401
 ---> c41f04004970
Step 5/37 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends        apt-utils             libcudnn7=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0             libcudnn7-dev=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 &&     apt-mark hold libcudnn7 &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Running in 3a67681d2578
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Ign:4 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Get:5 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release [170 B]
Get:6 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release [170 B]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [940 kB]
Get:8 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg [170 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg [170 B]
Get:11 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages [231 kB]
Get:12 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages [54.1 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1558 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [582 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [6114 B]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [9827 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [176 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1322 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [986 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [19.1 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [7942 B]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [8807 B]
Fetched 16.3 MB in 28s (570 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapt-inst2.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils libapt-inst2.0 libcudnn7 libcudnn7-dev
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 242 MB of archives.
After this operation, 598 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapt-inst2.0 amd64 1.2.32 [55.8 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apt-utils amd64 1.2.32 [196 kB]
Get:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  libcudnn7 7.3.0.29-1+cuda9.0 [126 MB]
^C
```

I can not see progress or rate from the log, then I delete the RUN part and finished image build and tried

```
docker container run --rm -it testimage /bin/bash
```

, and when the container is running, I run this:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-utils \
            libcudnn7=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 \
            libcudnn7-dev=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 && \
    apt-mark hold libcudnn7 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

, it works,the log is

```
root@74ce912f6318:/# apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
>     apt-utils \
>             libcudnn7=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 \
>             libcudnn7-dev=$CUDNN_VERSION-1+cuda9.0 && \
>     apt-mark hold libcudnn7 && \
>     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Ign:4 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Ign:5 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:7 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release [170 B]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1558 kB]
Get:9 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release [170 B]
Get:10 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg [170 B]
Get:11 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Release.gpg [170 B]
Get:12 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages [231 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [14.1 kB]
Get:14 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  Packages [54.1 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [9827 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [176 kB]                                                                                                                    
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1322 kB]                                                                                                                 
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [940 kB]                                                                                                                
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [12.7 kB]                                                                                                         
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [582 kB]                                                                                                            
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [6114 B]                                                                                                          
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages                                                                                                                     
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [986 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [19.1 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [7942 B]                                                                                                                
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [8807 B]                                                                                                            
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.1 kB]                                                                                                           
Fetched 16.3 MB in 39s (409 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapt-inst2.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils libapt-inst2.0 libcudnn7 libcudnn7-dev
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 242 MB of archives.
After this operation, 598 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapt-inst2.0 amd64 1.2.32 [55.8 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apt-utils amd64 1.2.32 [196 kB]
Get:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64  libcudnn7 7.3.0.29-1+cuda9.0 [126 MB]
31% [3 libcudnn7 63.8 MB/170 B 37523776%]                                                                                                                                               8995 kB/s 19s^C
```

This time, I can see the progress(i.e. 31%), I stop it myself with ctrl-c.

I have two expectations, first is to make the Dockerfile work, second is to see the progress. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure it stucked ? the file is 126MB, try to build using `--network=host`

Comment: @LinPy it works, thanks,but i still want to know if there is a way to see the progress.

Comment: Strange should be there

Comment: I suppose it's a network issue. You may want to change the mirror to use a location close to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror

Comment: Sidenote: You really don't want to see the progress. In the end, that is just noise. In my Dockerfiles, I always use apt with `-qq` flag, and I also like to pipe the output to `/dev/null `. You only want to see warning and erros in the end.

Comment: How long did you wait until you intercepted with ctrl + c?